# Swift CollectionView insets

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I know this has been asked loads of times, but I can't have a proper solution for now despite I have digged on this for quite long time.

I have a collectionview with an header implemented.

[image]

I want to have a space between the header and the main collection view.

I tried to implement insets as below:

```
@objc(collectionView:layout:insetForSectionAtIndex:)  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets{

    print("called insetForSectionAt with a section value of:  \(section)")

    if ( section == 1 ) {return UIEdgeInsetsMake(100, 0, 0, 0)}

    else {return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0) }

}
```

And got the below:

```
called insetForSectionAt with a section value of:  0 
called insetForSectionAt with a section value of:  0
called insetForSectionAt with a section value of:  0
called insetForSectionAt with a section value of:  0
called insetForSectionAt with a section value of:  0
called insetForSectionAt with a section value of:  0
```

So clearly this is doing nothing, ow can set the insets just for the main collectionview and not for the entire screen itself? If I use 100 as top inset for index0 this affects the header, which is not what I need.

Thanks.

Comment: How many sections do you have?  The first has index `0`.

Comment: Apparently just 1. I have an headerview and the maincollectionview.

Comment: [This picture](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscollectionviewflowlayout/1402862-sectioninset) shows what the insets do.  How does that compare to what you are seeing?

Comment: I know, but this is not what is happening in my case. If I set the insets for section0 they will apply also on the header.

Comment: Added pic for ease.